# Using Python with Schedule library with an IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement, schedule

Hoping for some help with scheduling a python script. I understand the syntax, but since I've added the IF statement logic, I can't get the script to run for two days in a row. The next morning it will either only run the daily job OR skips it entirely and only runs the fifteen-minute job. I need the if logic so the jobs runs on the weekdays only. Does anyone have a fix or a clever workaround to just have it run on on a weekday?

Thanks for the help. I included a simplified version of my code below:

```
import schedule
import time

def daily_job(text):
    print(text)

def fifteen_min_job():
    print('15 minute job...')

if True: # For example only run on weekdays
    schedule.every().day.at("09:32").do(daily_job, text='daily job...')
    schedule.every(15).minutes.do(fifteen_min_job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an IF statement, use this instead:

```
schedule.every(15).minutes.do(fifteen_min_job)
schedule.every().monday.at("09:32").do(daily_job, text='daily job...')
schedule.every().tuesday.at("09:32").do(daily_job, text='daily job...')
schedule.every().wednesday.at("09:32").do(daily_job, text='daily job...')
schedule.every().thursday.at("09:32").do(daily_job, text='daily job...')
schedule.every().friday.at("09:32").do(daily_job, text='daily job...')
```

This method is a lot more stable in the long run!

For running the 15 minute job on weekdays as well, just do this:

```
def weekdayJob:
    schedule.every(15).minutes.do(fifteen_min_job).tag("fifteen")

def clearJob:
    schedule.clear("fifteen")

schedule.every().monday.at("00:00").do(weekdayJob)
schedule.every().saturday.at("00:00").do(clearJob)
```

Comment: Ah, that is probably much more stable thank you! But what if I want the 15-minute job to only run on the weekdays too, or in this case, only run when the stock market is open? Is there a way to still use logic?

Comment: If you want that, just put the 15 minute job scheduler in a function, make 5 more schedulers for the weekdays to run just the 15 minute scheduler, and then make two more schedulers for the weekends to cancel the 15 minute scheduler. Make sense?